# How to send parameters to Stimulsoft Report in Asp.Net Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, stimulsoft

I use `Asp.net Core 2.0` Web Application.

I have a simple `stimulsoft` report file.

my report has a `parameter` Called `@ID`.

If I Use the report without parameter, it's working well, But When I send parameter to report, it's not working and report loaded empty.

my Code is:

```
var _Report = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
_Report.Load(@"C:\temp\report.mrt"); // load report
((StiSqlDatabase)_Report.Dictionary.Databases["Connection"]).ConnectionString = "new connectionString "; // change connection 
_Report.DataSources["DataSource1"].Parameters["@ID"].ParameterValue = 5171; // set parameter value   
_Report.Render();
```

Note: I use **Asp.net Core version 2.0**.

this code is working in `asp.net` well.

please help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow!!!

solved.

I should use from `Value` Instead `ParameterValue`.

Like below:

```
_Report.DataSources["DataSource1"].Parameters["@ID"].Value = 5171;
```